# WUAPI: Feature Updates

Tags: c#, windows, com, wuapi

I'm trying to install a feature update using WUAPI. I believe I need  [IUpdateInstaller4::Commit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wuapi/nf-wuapi-iupdateinstaller4-commit)  method but I cannot make it work. Without the commit method the feature update stays in the processing state after the installation. I already tried few things:

- `updateSession.CreateUpdateInstaller()` returns `IUpdateInstaller` not `IUpdateInstaller4`. Anyway I tried:

```
var updateInstaller4= (IUpdateInstaller4) updateSession.CreateUpdateInstaller();

// installation logic

updateInstaller4.Commit(1);
```

It got stuck for some time at the commit method and finished successfully but the update was not installed

- I also tried:

```
var updateInstaller4 = (IUpdateInstaller4) new WUApiLib.UpdateInstallerClass();
updateInstaller4.Commit(1);
```

But I get : 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x80240004'

Is it even a good approch to install the feature updates? Thank you for any help.

Comment: FWIW, 0x80240004 is WU_E_NOT_INITIALIZED so it looks like your API call workflow is broken

Comment: I am working on a project to list and install all pending windows updates. I am successfully able to do this, but when I use the WUAPI and do a search, Windows Features are not even listed. ***  ISearchResult uResult = uSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 or IsInstalled=1")... *** How did you even get the Feature to list, let alone install

Comment: @ChrisDunlop I can't remember what I passed to uSearcher.Search. But there was a strange parameter in addition to "IsInstalled=0 or IsInstalled=1". I know that I found it on github but I can't find it now. BTW we never succeeded with this project.